# Metric tensor $g$ for static gravitational field referred to static coordinate system

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

Assume there is static gravitational field. I want to deduce that there exists a coordinate system where $$g_{m0}=0, \quad m=1,2,3.$$ Is this a reasonable result? Why would it be contradictory if there is no such coordinate system?

I would be more than willing to show my thoughts but all I have is that it must be symmetric. I don't know the relationship between static i.e. time independent gravity and $g$. I can see that $g$ must be static as well since it has the analogy of classical gravitational potential.

Can I get some illumination on this?

Comment: Is your convention that Latin indices are spacelike? Be aware that the modern convention is different, with Latin indices usually being abstract, Greek ones concrete. One cannot generally prove results of the form "if the spacetime has this property, the metric looks like this." Usually one has results of the form "if the spacetime has this property, then there exist coordinates in which the metric looks like this." I think your claim is right when phrased in the latter form.

Comment: I have edited the question, so you can check if it is better suited phrase than before. I am having difficult time understanding the meaning of the metric tensor beyond peripheral meanings exhibited in $ds^2=g(dx,dx)$. How do you conceive $g$? Is it determined when space is fixed, or when coordinate system is fixed?

Comment: What is your definition of a static spacetime?

Comment: @Javier I actually haven't mentioned static spacetime, but I did mentioned static gravitational field.

Comment: Same thing. What is your definition? I mean, there is a standard one, just want to make sure we're on the same page.

Comment: I would define the curvature tensor is zero.